# What's the difference between (string[] args) and System.Environment.CommandLine?

Tags: .net, parameters, command-line-arguments

I'm inheriting maintenance on several console application that are entered, naturally, with `static void Main(string[] args)`. However, the code ignores the `args` array, and instead reads the command-line parameters from `System.Environment.CommandLine`.

Is there a functional difference, here?

The contents look identical. If anything, I would suspect a minute performance-hit by invoking `System.Environment.CommandLine` (but not enough that I would ever be concerned or care enough to measure).

---

UPDATE: I suspected that `System.Environment.CommandLine` should contain the executable path, but I wasn't seeing it... because I was looking in the wrong place. The code ALSO has `string[] arrCmdLine = System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();` .... `System.Environment.CommandLine.ToLower()` is checked for the presence of "debug" while all other params are extracted from `GetCommandLineArgs()` and I was mentally conflating the two while I was going "why not just use `args[]`?"

For years I've agonized over the best way of parsing command-line args, when all along it was "place them in the correct order!" [jk]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`System.Environment.CommandLine` includes the executable and arguments as a single string.

```
// Sample for the Environment.CommandLine property.
using System;

class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
        //  Invoke this sample with an arbitrary set of command line arguments.
        Console.WriteLine("CommandLine: {0}", Environment.CommandLine);
    }
}

/*
This example produces the following results:

C:\>env0 ARBITRARY TEXT

CommandLine: env0 ARBITRARY TEXT
*/
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.commandline.aspx

The `args` parameter is an array of arguments. So while you can parse the individual arguments from `System.Environment.CommandLine`, I'm not sure why you would want to. The only reason I can see is if you need to access arguments outside of `Main()`, which is probably a bad idea anyway. Your `Main()` method should handle arguments and pass them around the rest of the application as necessary.

Comment: What's the best way to split the args into an array using Environment.CommandLine? Reason being, My.Application.CommandLineArgs doesn't include quotes if they were in the arg(s). i.e. a path with strings was passed, which needs to be wrapped in quotes. Only way to accurately see the "raw" args including quotes is with Environment.CommandLine, but then it's not split into an array.